# Pandas drop ending tail zeros in column, grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've created following function do drop ending zeros in column "value" for each "proj".
But seems it's, so to speak, "not optimal") Hope someone coould give advise how to make it right.

Input tabble:

```
+---+------+---------+--------------+-------+
|   | proj | weeknum | weekduration | value |
+---+------+---------+--------------+-------+
| 0 |    1 |       1 |            4 |     0 |
| 1 |    1 |       2 |            4 |    11 |
| 2 |    1 |       3 |            4 |     0 |
| 3 |    1 |       4 |            4 |     0 |
| 4 |    2 |       1 |            4 |    10 |
| 5 |    2 |       2 |            4 |    11 |
| 6 |    2 |       3 |            4 |    12 |
| 7 |    2 |       4 |            4 |     0 |
+---+------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

For each "proj" we have to select and drop weeknum with "value" == zero, but only at the end (sort by "weeknum").

For this example I should get Indexes: `2, 3, 7`

```
+---+------+---------+--------------+-------+
|   | proj | weeknum | weekduration | value |
+---+------+---------+--------------+-------+
| 0 |    1 |       1 |            4 |     0 |
| 1 |    1 |       2 |            4 |    11 |
| 4 |    2 |       1 |            4 |    10 |
| 5 |    2 |       2 |            4 |    11 |
| 6 |    2 |       3 |            4 |    12 |
+---+------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

My simple draft code:

```
abnrm_list = []
for i in df.proj.unique():
    d = df[df['proj'] == i]
    last_week = d['weeknum'].max()
    cs_hrs = d[d['weeknum'] == last_week]['value'].values[0]
    while cs_hrs == 0:
        abnrm_list.append(d[d['weeknum'] == last_week].index[0])
        last_week = last_week - 1
        cs_hrs = d[d['weeknum'] == last_week]['value'].values[0]
```

But I'm sure should be some simpler clearer solution to this.

Also, need to update "weekduration" to new value after dropping zero rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filter out last `0` values compared by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) in helper `Series` created by swapping order of columns with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
mask = df['value'].iloc[::-1].groupby(df['proj']).cumsum().iloc[::-1].ne(0)
df = df[mask].copy()
print (df)
   proj  weeknum  weekduration  value
0     1        1             4      0
1     1        2             4     11
4     2        1             4     10
5     2        2             4     11
6     2        3             4     12
```

And then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['weekduration'] = df['proj'].map(df['proj'].value_counts())
print (df)
   proj  weeknum  weekduration  value
0     1        1             2      0
1     1        2             2     11
4     2        1             3     10
5     2        2             3     11
6     2        3             3     12
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['value'].iloc[::-1])
7     0
6    12
5    11
4    10
3     0
2     0
1    11
0     0
Name: value, dtype: int64

print (df['value'].iloc[::-1].groupby(df['proj']).cumsum())
7     0
6    12
5    23
4    33
3     0
2     0
1    11
0    11
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

**Performance**:

You need avoid filtering per groups, becuse slow:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'proj':np.random.randint(10000, size=N), 
                   'value': np.random.choice([0,1,2], N)}).sort_values('proj')
print (df)

In [76]: %timeit df.groupby('proj').apply(lambda grp: grp[grp.value[::-1].cumsum().gt(0)[::-1]]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
20.2 s ± 4.04 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [78]: %timeit df[df['value'].iloc[::-1].groupby(df['proj']).cumsum().iloc[::-1].ne(0)]
268 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

To drop trailing zeroes run:

```
result = df.groupby('proj').apply(
    lambda grp: grp[grp.value[::-1].cumsum().gt(0)[::-1]])\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

The lambda function:

- takes *value* column in reversed order,
- computes *cumsum*,
- converts to *bool* (is cumsum > 0),
- reverts back to the "original" order,
- uses boolean indexing to drop trailing zeroes.

The above procedure is repeated for all *proj* groups.

All that remains to be done (at this step) is *reset_index* to drop the
top level of the index (grouping keys).

And now the second part - update *weekduration*:

```
result.weekduration = result.groupby('proj').weekduration\
    .transform(lambda grp: grp.size)
```

The final result is:

```
   proj  weeknum  weekduration  value
0     1        1             2      0
1     1        2             2     11
4     2        1             3     10
5     2        2             3     11
6     2        3             3     12
```

## Edit

Or if you prefer an "all in one" solution, then define the following
function to filter a group and at the same time set *weekduration*:

```
def myFilter(grp):
    grp = grp[grp.value[::-1].cumsum().gt(0)[::-1]]
    grp.weekduration = grp.index.size
    return grp
```

Then compute the result, applying this function to each group (grouped
by *proj*):

```
result = df.groupby('proj').apply(myFilter).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```